# Poor grammar choice on FAQ page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-contents

I noticed this section in the [UX FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq):

> #### What makes a good question?
>
> Prefer questions that elicit definitive answers or solutions rather
> than prolonged discussions. Remember, this a Q&A site, not a
> discussion board.

"*Prefer questions...*" sounds very awkward and unnatural, although it could be technically correct as in "**You should** prefer questions..."  (a command to prefer questions).

I think it should be changed from "Prefer" to "**We** prefer", or even something a bit stronger like:

> "[Please] only ask questions that elicit definitive answers...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. Thanks for the suggestion!